# Is it possible to reinstall Postresql without destroying existing databases?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I have a Postgresql 10 installation on Ubuntu 18.04 that somehow broke and won't restart. Can I just reinstall it without destroying its databases, so that I can access the databases again? pg_dump doesn't work.

Comment: It's usually better to investigate _why_ Postgres doesn't start rather than re-installing it. Maybe it refuses to start because something is wrong with the data directory. Then a re-install wouldn't change a thing. A look into the log file could reveal the reason.

Comment: It began when I changed the pg_hba.conf which caused the cluster to not start. The error said a 'postmaster.pid' was left over, so I removed it, and now I can't make a postmaster.pid file even if I chmod the dir. I get an error FATAL:  could not create lock file "postmaster.pid": Permission denied

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that.
By default, your databases and other important files are stored in PGDATA.

> Traditionally, the configuration and data files used by a database cluster are stored together within the cluster's data directory, commonly referred to as PGDATA (after the name of the environment variable that can be used to define it). A common location for PGDATA is /var/lib/pgsql/data.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/storage-file-layout.html

I don't know how you will uninstall PostgreSQL, but be sure to keep PGDATA.
(yum or apt won't delete PGDATA)
After re-installing PostgreSQL, make sure to launch your PostgreSQL with your existing PGDATA

```
pg_ctl start -D YOUR_EXISTING_PGDATA/
```